# Как объединить два изображения с учетом прозрачности (PHP, Imagick)?

Tags: php, imagick

Есть два графических файла. 
Первый файл – фоновый рисунок в формате JPG

Второй файл – PNG с фигурой в центре с черной рамкой по контуру.

**Вопрос:**
Как объединить два файла с сохранением прозрачности? Фон из первого файла нужно поместить внутри фигуры на втором файле (см.пример).

[image: Пример]

**Изображения:**

PNG file - profiles.in.ua/tmp/sample2.jpg

JPG file - profiles.in.ua/tmp/sample1.png

Пробую делать так:

```
    $mask = new Imagick(realpath('mask.png'));

    $pattern = new Imagick(realpath('pattern.jpg'));

    $pattern->resizeImage($mask->width, $mask->height, Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

    $pattern->compositeImage($mask, Imagick::COMPOSITE_ATOP, 0, 0);

    header("Content-Type: image/png");

    echo $pattern->getImageBlob();

    $mask->destroy();

    $pattern->destroy();
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это дубликат

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте один и тот же вопрос многократно. Если есть сомнения - читайте справку. [ask].

Comment: С каких пор дубликаты закрывают так?

Comment: @Qwertiy в случаях, когда дублирующий вопрос не содержит плюсанутых ответов, объявить вопрос "главным" и указывать дубликаты на него нельзя. Часто это означает, что оба вопроса одинаково бесполезны, хотя всякое бывает .-. Здесь можно сделать скорее в обратную сторону, если я правильно понимаю механизм, но ссылки на дубликат нет, чтобы удостовериться.

Answer (score 1):

У себя использовал нечто вроде такого, может вам поможет

```
$img_path = "img1.jpg"; //передаем скрипту изображение, на которое нужно что-то наложить, в формате .jpg
$watermark = "watermark.png"; //тут хранится путь к накладываемому изображению, в формате .png
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($img_path); //создаем исходное изображение
$water_img = imagecreatefrompng($watermark); //создаем водный знак
$water_size = getimagesize($water_img); //узнаем размеры водного знака, чтобы правильно выполнить наложение
imagecopy($img, $water_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $water_size[0], $water_size[1]); //накладываем водный знак на изображение по заданным координатам.
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($img, $water_img , 100);
```